# get the index number of data gotten from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to get all user data from my mysql table and i want to check the index number of where a particular data is for example if there are 10 users in the database and after getting the data from it i want to check if any of the user ID matches the one i have then get the index number where he is placed at. if his data is in number 4 or 8

```
    $userId= '****';
    $active = 'active';
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status=? ORDER BY date DESC, class DESC");
    $sql->bind_param("s", $active);
    $sql->execute();
    $res = $sql->get_result();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while ($row = $res -> fetch_assoc()) {
            if($userId == $row['userId']) {

               ///Get the number he is in the array of 10 users...

            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode("no_user");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "index number"?

Comment: If there's an auto-increment ID column in the table, that column should be what you want.

Comment: @Barmar i used an order by so i can't really used that because it will be mixed up and what i mean by index number is where it's placed in the `$row` array which starts from `0, 1, 2, ... 9` and i want to check which one has a userId that matches the one am looking for and what's it index number

Comment: `$row` is an associative array of columns, not an array of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment a counter variable in the loop.

```
        $index = 0;
        while ($row = $res -> fetch_assoc()) {
            if($userId == $row['userId']) {
               echo $index;
            }
            $index++;
        }
```